# Writing HTML into a new tab

Tags: html, google-chrome, tabs, google-chrome-extension

In my extension, I'm creating a new tab and would like to write my own html to it - that's generated dynamically.

Can it be done.

I'm calling `chrome.tabs.create()` to create a new tab - now I just need to write my data as an HTML file to it.

Answer (score 11):

Easiest way to do this would be using a [data: URL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme). E.g. something like this:

```js
var htmlCode = "<html><body>Hi!</body></html>";
var url = "data:text/html," + encodeURIComponent(htmlCode);
chrome.tabs.create({url: url});
```